# JSF Ajax event not extending session.maxInactiveInterval

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, session-timeout

I have two web pages `index.xhtml` and `sessionExpiry.xhtml`.  Objective is to redirect user to `sessionExpiry.xhtml` page upon timeout.  I have made session timeout to be 1 minute in `web.xml`.  I am using `http-equiv=refresh` tag to redirect user upon timeout.
`index.xhtml` has a mandatory text field which displays a error message upon `onblur event` if nothing is entered.  Added a `HttpSessionListener` to record session creation and destruction.

**Test scenario:** Open the web page in browser, session creation time displayed on server logs, after 15 seconds, clicked on input text box and clicked outside and rich error message is displayed.  Left the web page idle, web page redirects to `sessionExpiry.xhtml` after 1 min (I was expecting this to happen after 1 min 15 sec), but the session destroyed message on server logs is happening around 2-3 mins.

Why is the session destroyed delayed?  How can I make session expiry happen after 1 min of inactivity after AJAX event?  Following is the source code.

`web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        1
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sessiontimeout.HttpSessionChecker</listener-class>
</listener>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

`index.xhtml`

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="#{session.maxInactiveInterval};url=./sessionExpiry.xhtml" />
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            Hello from Facelets
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                Enter some text:
                <h:inputText id="txt" required="true" maxlength="16" size="20"
                             autocomplete="off" requiredMessage="Text is Required">
                    <f:ajax event="blur" render="txtmsg" />
                </h:inputText>
                <rich:message id="txtmsg" for="txt" />
            </h:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

`sessionExpiry.xhtml`

```
<h:body>
        Session Timed out after ${session.maxInactiveInterval/60} minutes of inactivity.
</h:body>
```

`HttpSessionChecker.java`

```
public class HttpSessionChecker implements HttpSessionListener {

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Session ID " + event.getSession().getId() + " created at " + new Date());
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Session ID " + event.getSession().getId() + " destroyed at " + new Date());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I was expecting this to happen after 1 min 15 sec*

You set the timeout to one minute, so it timed out after one minute. You needed to do a synchronous postback to update that meta element or update that element via JS when ajax call succeeds and that will *probably* prolong the event (see [Is it possible to use javascript to change the meta-tags of the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2568760/is-it-possible-to-use-javascript-to-change-the-meta-tags-of-the-page)).

*The session destroyed message on server logs is happening around 2-3 mins*

There is no restriction on *when exactly* the session will be invalidated by container upon timeout event (see [recognizing session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223841/recognizing-session-timeout)). The contract tells that it *will be invalidated* at some time but not exactly when it times out and it *won't count as active* anymore. For instant invalidation there is invalidate-and-send-redirect approach instead (see [JSF logout using session.invalidate does not clear the current username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899500/jsf-logout-using-session-invalidate-does-not-clear-the-current-username)).

*Why is the session destroyed delayed? How can I make session expiry happen after 1 min of inactivity after AJAX event?*

These questions are basically answered above. See also the following questions on how to deal with session expiration events properly:

1. [How to handle session expiration and ViewExpiredException in JSF 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992526/how-to-handle-session-expiration-and-viewexpiredexception-in-jsf-2)
2. [javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored)
3. [Session timeout and ViewExpiredException handling on JSF/PrimeFaces ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203195/session-timeout-and-viewexpiredexception-handling-on-jsf-primefaces-ajax-request)

Comment: I was expecting AJAX call to reset the counter.  Will try jQuery solution.  Thanks.